# Como disparar um trigger com jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, trigger

Estou trabalhando com botão do tipo radio e não consigo disparar um trigger. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

```
$("input[name='estimate_method']").on('change', function() {

    $(this).prop("checked", true);
    $("input[name='do']").trigger("click");

});
```

Imagem da situação ... se der certo eu vou esconder esse **Atualizar Total** e mandar um trigger em cima dele. O html do botão é:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="do" value="Atualizar Total">            
     <span>
         <span>Atualizar Total</span>
     </span>
</button>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele entra dentro do **on("change")** mas não disparar a ação em cima do botão. O objetivo é, na hora que eu clicar num radio, ele disparar o trigger no **Atualizar Total**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder usar o `trigger` do jquery você deve previamente atribuir uma função ao determinado evento que desejas disparar, por exemplo:

No evento *click* do botão uso um `.preventDefault()` e depois uso a função `.submit()` no *form*, assim o botão tem a mesma função mas agora essa está declarada e o evento pode ser reconhecido pelo jquery:

```
$('form button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').submit();
})
```

Agora sim, posso usar o *trigger*:

```
$('form input:radio').on('change', function(){
    $('form button').trigger('click')
});
```

Se quiser apenas submeter o *form*, pode usar o [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) que usei acima.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k3pgephn/)

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou muuuuuito !! Obrigado.